# Only the first instance of recapcha gets reset using grecaptcha.reset()

Tags: angular

I am using ngx recapcha in my angular app.
I have both login and register form in one modal.
I reset the recapcha using `grecaptcha.reset();` when modal is closed but only the first instance of recapcha which is in login component gets reset the recapcha in register component doesn't.

I even tried to put `grecaptcha.reset();` in individual login and register component but still the same issue even the `grecaptcha.reset();` in the register component doesnt work it resets the recapcha of the login component not the recapcha of register component.

This is the structure home-component.html

```
<div class="modal">
<app-login></app-login>
<app-register></app-register>
</div>
```

Inside the html

```
    <re-captcha [ngClass]="{'face err-captcha': captchaResponse==false && submitted}"
              class="recaptcha" (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey={{captchaSiteKey}}>
 </re-captcha>
```

ts

```
resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
    if(captchaResponse !== null) {
      this.data.verifyCaptcha(captchaResponse).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        if(res.success) {
          this.captchaResponse = true;
          }
      });
    } else {
      this.captchaResponse = false;
      alert("Cant connect to google recaptcha");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You say... **inside the html** , but inside what html? Where is the re-captcha placed and which ts is that code in?

Comment: its in <re-captcha tag

Comment: yeah, but which component, and which component is the TS in? please provide a [mcve]